# Doctrine: ignore new columns before mapping is deployed

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

I run into issues when I add a new column to an existing table mapped by Doctrine. I usually update the schema first and then I deploy the code with the mappings. However, between these two steps I get errors like:

`Property MyEntity::$newcolumn does not exist" at /app/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php line 80`

Ideally Doctrine would ignore a new column before the mapping is deployed and just let there be a default value. Is there a way to do this? I'm aware of Doctrine migrations but it seems to be too much hassle to solve a simple issue like this.

My Doctrine version: 2.5

Comment: I think your issue is not deploy workflow, but some cache (apc, opcache or doctrine cache). Migration won't solve this problem. Just to be sure, you get these errors between deploy steps or after code deploy ?

Comment: Agreed with @dpa - it is most probably metadata/annotation cache - investigate in Doctrine configuration.